# Здрасьте, есть такая вот запись, что значит строчка Main main = new Main();

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
    void useCar(Car car) {
        car.driving();
        System.out.println(car.getNumOfSeets());
    }
    public static voidmain(String[] args) {
        Main main = new Main();
        Car car = new Toyota();
        main.useCar(car);
    }
}
```

Comment: И я бы в вопросе слово 'Здрасьте' не писал бы). Лучше задать вопрос со слово 'что...'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь ты создаёшь экземпляр класса Main с помощью пустого(дефолтного) конструтора(Main()).

У тебя есть класс `Main` в нём есть 2 метода `useCar` и `main`. Метод `main`(благодаря этому методу `java` понимает откуда начинать ему работу) запускается самой `java` и в `main` ты создаёшь класс типа `Main`(Если у класса нет явной реализации конструктора, то он создаётся пустой конструктор самой `java` ) и `Car`.